# Hide column of table dynamically using jquery $(object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple table with two columns and with custom property "data-cid". I want hide column based on data-cid proerpty.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("th[data-cid='Col_17']").each(function(index, obj) {
    if ($(obj).prop("className") == "")
      $(obj).attr("class", "hide-elem");
    else
      $(obj).addClass("hide-elem");
  });

}
$("td[data-colId='Col_17']").each(function(index, obj) {
  if ($(obj).prop("class") == "")
    $(obj).attr("class", "hide-elem");
  else
    $(obj).addClass("hide-elem");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-cid="Col_18">sadf</th>
      <th data-cid="Col_17">asdf</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-cid="Col_18">sadf</td>
      <td data-cid="Col_17">sadf</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the above browser wasn't able to add class to my th and td. can someone help me what's wrong??

Comment: You could do both in a single loop with the selector `$("th[data-cid='Col_17'], td[data-cid='Col_17']")`

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:-**

> You have an extra `}` in your code

**Try this:-**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("th[data-cid='Col_17'], td[data-cid='Col_17']").each(function(index, obj) {
            if($(obj).prop("className") == ""){
                $(obj).attr("class", "hide-elem");
            }else{
                $(obj).addClass("hide-elem");
            }
        });

        
       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<thead>
<tr><th data-cid="Col_18">sadf</th>
<th data-cid="Col_17">asdf</th></tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td data-cid="Col_18">sadf</td>
<td data-cid="Col_17">sadf</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` between the two loops. But you can simply combine them into a single loop by putting both selectors together. You also had a typo in the `td` selector, you had `data-colId` instead of `data-cid`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("th[data-cid='Col_17'], td[data-cid='Col_17']").each(function(index, obj) {
    if ($(obj).prop("className") == "")
      $(obj).attr("class", "hide-elem");
    else
      $(obj).addClass("hide-elem");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-elem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-cid="Col_18">sadf</th>
      <th data-cid="Col_17">asdf</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-cid="Col_18">sadf</td>
      <td data-cid="Col_17">sadf</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra `}` and your jquery selector is wrong. it should be `$("th[data-cid='Col_17']")`instead `$("th[data-cid='Col_17']")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$("th[data-cid='Col_17']").each(function(index, obj) {
    if ($(obj).prop("className") == "")
      $(obj).attr("class", "hide-elem");
    else
      $(obj).addClass("hide-elem");
  });
  
  
$("td[data-cid=Col_17]").each(function(index, obj) {

  if ($(obj).prop("class") == "")
    $(obj).attr("class", "hide-elem");
  else
    $(obj).addClass("hide-elem");
});
});
```

```css
.hide-elem{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-cid="Col_18">sadf</th>
      <th data-cid="Col_17">asdf</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-cid="Col_18">sadf</td>
      <td data-cid="Col_17">sadf</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```